# MongoDB connection error after an idle application period

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

We have this behavior of MongoDB connection which is unable to be traced; the MongoDB connections after some application idle time starts getting MongoDB connection error for every request made by the application. Only after the restart of the AppServer ('Tomcat', the application is deployed on) the MongoDB connections are reacquired and works well.

Want to know if anyone have come across such an issue and probable configuration solution. One another way which I think is then to Exception handle and do a retry for getting the connection.

NOTE: Java 1.7, Spring 3.1.x have been used for Server code. MongoDB Version: 2.6.9. Mongo Driver: mongo-2.10.1

Comment: Can you please provide some code where you are initializing your application.

Answer (score -1):

Use these options for performance and preventing this problem.

```
autoConnectRetry = true
connectTimeout = 3000
connectionsPerHost = 40
socketTimeout = 120000
threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 5
maxAutoConnectRetryTime=5
maxWaitTime=120000
```